# function utilization - calling using apply vs direct call

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have code as below. If I call the function by the first method, it works. But if I call the function using the second method, I get an error. I thought that method two should work as the function is expecting columns as its input. Why do we have to say that run the function over columns as described in method 1?

`train` is the `pandas` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
        else:
            return 24
    else:
        return Age

#pd.isnull(train[['Age']])

#method 1
#train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age, axis=1)

#method 2
impute_age(train[['Age','Pclass']])
```

Comment: What is `pd` and most importantly: what is `train`?

Comment: pd=pandas and train is a dataframe..sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need a well-formatted code:

```
import pandas as pd
def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):

        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37

        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29

        else:
            return 24

    else:
        return Age


#pd.isnull(train[['Age']])

#method 1
#train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)

#method 2
impute_age(train[['Age','Pclass']])
```

In one word, you need indents after `def`.